# Try-with-resources stream closed unexpectedly

Tags: java, channel, try-with-resources

I have the following set of code to write a business object to a file. The writing is usually done in two parts but `writeTrx`-helper here does both temporary file writing and renaming:

```
public static void writeTrx(File dbDir, Trx trx, String idString) throws IOException {
    UnfinishedTrx temp = writeTempTrxFile(dbDir, trx, idString);
    finishWritingTrx(temp);
}

public static UnfinishedTrx writeTempTrxFile(File dbDir, Trx trx, String idString) throws IOException {
    File tempDir = getAndCreateTempDir(dbDir);
    Path tempFilePath = Files.createTempFile(tempDir.toPath(), idString, ".tmp_trx");
    try (OutputStream fos = Files.newOutputStream(tempFilePath)) {
        writeTrx(fos, trx);
    }
    return new UnfinishedTrx(dbDir, idString, tempFilePath);
}

public static void writeTrx(OutputStream out, Trx trx) throws IOException {
    try (BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(out);
         ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(bos)) {
        oos.writeObject(trx);
    }
}
```

I do, however, get from time to time `java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException` from this:

```
at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.ensureOpen(FileChannelImpl.java:99)
at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.write(FileChannelImpl.java:192)
at java.nio.channels.Channels.writeFullyImpl(Channels.java:78)
at java.nio.channels.Channels.writeFully(Channels.java:101)
at java.nio.channels.Channels.access$000(Channels.java:61)
at java.nio.channels.Channels$1.write(Channels.java:174)
at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.write(BufferedOutputStream.java:126)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream$BlockDataOutputStream.drain(ObjectOutputStream.java:1876)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream$BlockDataOutputStream.writeByte(ObjectOutputStream.java:1914)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeFatalException(ObjectOutputStream.java:1575)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:350)
at foo.TrxHelper.writeTrx(TrxHelper.java:125)
at foo.TrxHelper.writeTempTrxFile(TrxHelper.java:99)
at foo.TrxHelper.writeTrx(TrxHelper.java:91)
```

Which leaves me mystified. How can the channel get closed with such call structure as ObjectOutputStream closes the stream *only* when close is called?

My understanding is that the stream should get closed at earliest when the inner writeTrx-call is to return, not within it.

Comment: Good question but you should also note that it's writing an exception. Are you sure `Trx` and its members are always `Serializable`? And are these the only two `writeTrx()`methods? The line numbering doesn't agree.

Comment: Indeed. Somehow, I was blind to the fact that it was writing an Exception. Trx is always serializable as it's using a serialization proxy. Even if it were not, writeFatalException should write `NotSerializableException` and throw it afterwards. That is not the case here.

Comment: Well it's writing something, which can be any `IOException` at all. Hard to say what.

Comment: I am specifically interested in how `ClosedChannelException` can get thrown at that point. Does some action-at-distance close the channel in the middle of a write?

Comment: In any case, I don't see how the channel underneath would get closed as none of the try-with-resources -blocks have exited yet and neither  `ObjectOutputStream` nor `BufferedOutputStream` close the underlying streams on errors.